# Regex with brackets

Tags: php, c, regex, preg-match, phalcon

I am looking for some help with regex.

I have this piece of code:

```
$router->add( 
    '/activate/{token:[a-zA-Z0-9]+}', 
    array (
        'module' => 'frontend',
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'activate'
    )
);
```

which works just fine. However the one below does not:

```
$router->add( 
    '/activate/{token:[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}}', 
    array (
        'module' => 'frontend',
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'activate'
    )
);
```

The matching mechanism that I have in C is (which works with preg_match_all also)

```
'#{([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*)(:([^}]+))*}#'
```

I would appreciate some pointers as to how to make the second example work.

**EDIT**

```
preg_match_all(
    '#{([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*)(:([^}]+))*}#',
    '/manual/{language:[a-z]{2}}/{file:[a-z]+}.html',
    $matches,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
```

I want it to return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {language:[a-z]{2}}
            [1] => language
            [2] => :[a-z]{2}
            [3] => [a-z]{2}
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {file:[a-z]+}
            [1] => file
            [2] => :[a-z]+
            [3] => [a-z]+
        )
)
```

Comment: Is the token you are matching in the second example 32 characters of just [a-zA-Z0-9]?  What routes isn't it matching and is it because another route is taking precedence because they're ambigious?

Comment: Please add some examples showing text for which the first one works and the second doesn't.

Comment: Are you trying to make the second pattern match exactly 32 characters or a limit of up to 32 characters? If it's the latter, you'll need to use {1,32} instead.

Comment: Added more information. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression: '#{([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)(:(.*)}?)}#' works for both of them:

```
<?php

preg_match_all(
    '#{([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*)(:([^}]+}?))*}#',
    '/activate/{token:[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}}',
    $matches,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
print_r($matches);

preg_match_all(
    '#{([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]*)(:([^}]+}?))*}#',
    '/activate/{token:[a-zA-Z0-9]+}',
    $matches,
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
print_r($matches);
```